# I have an error while applying my iOS application with firebase

Tags: ios, swift

Error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCore(FIRBundleUtil.o)
  "_GULResetLogger", referenced from:
      _FIRResetLogger in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerRegisterVersion", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerInitializeASL", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
      _FIRLogBasic in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerEnableSTDERR", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
      _FIRIsLoggableLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
      _FIRSetLoggerLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerForceDebug", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And I used cocoapods

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'drivethru' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for drivethru
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
 pod 'Firebase'

end
```

Comment: Searching for "GULAppEnvironmentUtil" tells me it's related to Google Utilities.  It seems that comes from a library that you need to link in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Theres no need to use `pod 'Firebase/Core'` and `pod 'Firebase'`.

Remove those and only put the ones you need according to [Google Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

For example lets suppose you are only using Firestore and FireStorage, you would only need to add those pods:

`'Firebase/Storage'`
`'Firebase/Firestore'`

Hope it works