# Firebase iOS - Undefined symbol: _GULResetLogger (arm64)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm getting the following error when building my iOS app with XCode 12.0:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GULResetLogger", referenced from:
      _FIRResetLogger in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MyApp' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
end
```

Previously my Podfile also contained `pod 'Firebase/Core'` but I've removed it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251009/4136777) and re-installed my dependencies using the commands found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534917/4136777):

```sh
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

I've also run `pod update` to make sure I've got the latest dependencies, but I'm still getting the same error.

How can I get my app to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging I was finally able to work around this by doing the following:

1. Downgrade to Xcode 11.7 ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14756127/4136777))
2. Clean install dependencies ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534917/4136777))
3. *Clean Build Folder* in under the *Product* menu in Xcode.

I still was not able to run the app on my device because iOS 14 is not supported by Xcode 11 (MobileDeviceErrorDomain error -402653150). Here is how I fixed this:

1. Install Device Support files for iOS 14.0 ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63556220/4136777))
2. Unpair device from Xcode
3. Restart iPhone
4. Clean Build Folder